# find value in JSON from list in text file

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish:
Use contents of a text file to search for values in JSON file.

My text file contains one entry per line. The will match values in the JSON file.

```
thing1
thing2
thing3
```

I would like to iterate this list and return matches from the JSON file

```json
{
  "ssb": [
    {
      "uid": 27,
      "appid": "thing1",
      "title": "Title of thing",
      "created_time": "2009-11-17T01:32:28+00:00",
      "published_time": "2009-11-17T01:32:28+00:00",
      "updated_time": "2022-11-14T17:26:23+00:00",
     }
   ]
 }
```

```py
import json

upgrade_apps = open("apps_to_upgrade.txt", "r")
ua = upgrade_apps.readlines()
upgrade_apps.close()
ua3 = "thing1"

#Testing results
print(ua)
print(type(ua))
for atu in ua:
    print(atu)
##  ^ this returns the expected text from file

with open('dump.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
f.close()
jsonResult = data['ssb']
for i in jsonResult:
    if i['appid'] == ua3: #<THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK> If i use ua3 OR "thing1" i get the expected result
        print(i['uid'],i['appid'])
        break
```

I have also tried including a for loop before the first for loop. I get back only the last entry in the text file.

```py
#all of the above codeblock plus

for atu in ua:
    with open('dump.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    jsonResult = data['ssb']
    for i in jsonResult:
        if i['appid'] == atu:
            print(i['uid'],i['appid'])
            break
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Make sure your code reproduces the problem.  As it stands, `ua = upgrade_apps.readline()` will fail because `upgrade_apps` is not defined.  Provide inputs that produce the problem (short sample files).

Comment: `for atu in ua:` is looping over the characters in the line, not looping over lines. `ua` is just the first line of the file.

Comment: The line returned by `readline()` ends with a newline. You need to remove that before comparing with the JSON data.

Comment: Hard to say with no clue what your data looks like

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited to provide better clarity.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Replaced code.

Comment: @Barmar Replaced code

Comment: @Dan added example of the JSON and text data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the newlines from the lines in `ua`, and turn it into a `set`. Then you can test if `i['appid']` is in the set.

```
import json

with open("apps_to_upgrade.txt", "r") as upgrade_apps
    ua = set(line.strip() for line in upgrade_apps)

with open('dump.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

jsonResult = data['ssb']
for i in jsonResult:
    if i['appid'] in ua:
        print(i['uid'],i['appid'])
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me a lot of manual work. I am not familliar with set and will be researching how it works. Again, thank you kind internet stranger.